# Plot with multiple y axis with multiple lines

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-analysis

I am very new with Python but I want to plot data from a .csv-file. In this .csv-file I have 8 columns. It is no problem for me to plot with one y-axis but I need three.

One y-axis for column #2 with axis limits 0 and 100.

One y axis for column #1 and #6 with axis limits 0 and 20000.

And one y axis for the remaining 5 columns  with axis limits 0 to 1000.

Is there some easy way to make such a plot?

I hope my english  is understandable.

Best regards!

Comment: Something [like this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html)?

Comment: Yey but I need more lines, so how can I add them? My (maybe stupid) idea did not work: p1, = host.plot([0, 1, 2], [[0, 1, 2],[1,2,3]], ["b-","c-"], label="Density")

Comment: You need separate plot statements for each set of lines. Using the same axis (e.g. `par2`) multiple times will plot them together.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you very much. Sorry that I haven't found the page by myself.